# How to display NUnit test results only when some tests failed?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, automation, nunit

When I build a Visual Studio 2010 project, I want to run unit tests with NUnit and display test results only when some tests have failed.

I have setup a post-build event in Visual Studio to call a batch file like below:

```
$(ProjectDir)RunUnitTest.bat "$(SolutionDir)packages\NUnit.Runners.2.6.0.12051\tools\nunit-console.exe" "$(TargetPath)"
```

Then in `RunUnitTest.bat`, I call `nunit-console.exe` and pass in the test project dll.

```
@echo off    
REM runner is the full path to nunit-console.exe
set runner=%1    
REM target is the full path to the dll containing unit tests
set target=%2    
"%runner%" "%target%"    
if errorlevel 1 goto failed
if errorlevel 0 goto passed    
:failed
echo some tests failed
goto end    
:passed
echo all tests passed
goto end    
:end
echo on
```

After that, NUnit generates `TestResult.xml` containing test results, so how do I display it in user friendly way? It'll be the best if it displays inside Visual Studio, but other options are open too.

Comment: I would strongly recommend simply using a VS integrated test runner: [TestDriven.Net](http://testdriven.net/) shows test results in the VS output pane, while [NCrunch](http://www.ncrunch.net/) runs all your tests automatically (and selectively) as you code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [nunit-summary](https://launchpad.net/nunit-summary/) to generate all pass summary html reports and [nunit-results](https://launchpad.net/nunit-results/) to create failed test reports in html.

This approach is quiet easy to setup.

First, download nunit-summary and nunit-results from launchpad and put them in TestRunner folder under the test project.

Then, add a post-build event to call a batch file.

Lastly, add the batch file to TestRunner folder under test project. It should contain the following files at the least:

- `nunit-results.exe`
- `nunit-results.tests.dll`
- `nunit-results.tests.pdb`
- `nunit-summary.exe`
- `nunit-core.dll
- `nunit.util.dll`
- `RunUnitTests.bat`

Post-build event for the project containing unit tests:

```
"$(ProjectDir)TestRunner\RunUnitTests.bat" "$(SolutionDir)packages\NUnit.Runners.2.6.0.12051\tools\nunit-console.exe" "$(TargetPath)" "$(TargetDir)"
```

Scripts in `RunUnitTest.bat`

```
REM     This batch file does the followings:
REM     1. runs unit test with nunit-console.exe and produces a TestResult.xml
REM     2. if one or more tests failes, it calls unit-results.exe to convert TestResult.xml to 
REM     Usage: RunUnitTests.bat "path-to-nunit.exe" "path-to-test.dll" "path-to-output-folder"

@echo off

REM get input arguments
set runner=%1
set target=%2
set output=%3

REM remove double quotes
set runner=%runner:"=%
set target=%target:"=%
set output=%output:"=%

REM prepare and clean up TestResult folder
if not exist "%output%TestResults\nul" md "%output%TestResults"
del "%output%\TestResults\*.*" /q

"%runner%" "%target%"

if errorlevel 1 goto failed
if errorlevel 0 goto passed

:failed
echo some tests failed
"%~dp0nunit-results.exe" "%output%TestResult.xml"
"%output%TestResults\index.html"
exit 1

:passed
echo all tests passed
"%~dp0nunit-summary.exe" "%output%TestResult.xml" -out=TestResults\TestSummary.html
"%output%TestResults\TestSummary.html"
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider XSLT to perform a transformation and display the results from TestResult.xml.